# Frequent CPU spikes on fresh install

Tags: mysql, performance

I just reinstalled my Server (Windows Server 2008 R2) and after installing MySQL 5.6, the CPU spikes every few seconds:

http://s15.postimg.org/dno7ztfjf/cpuspikes.png

Even worse than the higher CPU load compared to my old setup is that the spikes are accompanied by an audible sound from my hard drive (which is fine, I just checked), so I definitely want to get rid of this issue.

It's a fresh install only accessible from my local LAN, so unsurprisingly `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` returns just 2 rows (the `Query` itself and `Sleep`).

I tried Google but couldn't find anything, so I would really appreciate some help on this!